I have folder named dist that was generated using Babel. Can I directly use the contents of this folder in a new react project?
I have a React library that is published on npm. I follow the below steps for publishing on npm

I generate a folder named dist using Babel by running the command-

babel ./src -d ./dist


Then I publish the generated dist folder on npm.

Every time before publishing an update on npm, I want to be able to use the contents of the dist folder in another React project so that I can test it. I want to do this to avoid publishing buggy code on npm.

That's what npm link is for. You link your package name to its local project folder, then whenever you use npm install for any project that uses it, npm will install it from your local project instead of pulling it from the npm registry. (so everything else is the same: you keep doing exactly what you'd do if it was a normal package, because your other projects should have no idea that something's different)

I found an article which has a step-by-step guide for this.
different-approaches-to-testing-your-own-packages
It explains in detail five different approaches to solve this problem
